# How do I run Next.js app after cloning repository

Tags: reactjs, git, npm, next.js

I created a Next.js app using `npx create-next-app@latest`, pushed the new app to a GitHub repository, then cloned the repository into a new directory. When I tried to run the app using `npm run dev`, I got the following output:

```
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mini-warehouse@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mini-warehouse@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

I was expecting the development server to start. How can I run my app?

Comment: In order to run your Next.js app, you will need to install the necessary dependencies by running the command 'npm install' in the directory of the cloned repository. Once you have done this, you should be able to start the development server by running 'npm run dev'.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps

1. Navigate to root directory
2. Run command `npm install` or `yarn install`
3. After that start the server by command `npm run dev` or `yarn dev`
4. Development server should be running and you can visit your app at `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 2):

> npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

**run** : `npm install`

NOTE : you have always to install `node_modules` after coloning a repo. because when you push inside a repo the `.gitignore` file by default ignores `node_modules` folder because of its size so you should install it by running `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

the last line from you error stack is telling you the problem
Your projet has an package.json but you didn't install your dependencies

You should install before trying to run you project
running **npm install** and then **npm run dev**

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json

if you want to know more about package.json

Answer (score 0):

In the VS Code terminal run the following:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

try updating your nodejs version to latest one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).